# Jquery Ajax Call - Bootstrap alert on Success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to show a alert on form when submit action is ended.

My js function:

```
    function submitForm(){

    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var nomeCompleto = $("#nomeCompleto").val();
    var email    = $("#email").val();
    var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var parametros = {
                  "nomeCompleto" : name,
                  "email"        : email

          };

          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "adminRegistro.php",
                data: parametros,
                async:false,
                success: function(result){
                  var parsedData = JSON.parse(result);

                    $("#ajax-alert").addClass("alert alert-danger").text(parsedData.msg);
                    $("#ajax-alert").alert();
                    $("#ajax-alert").fadeTo(5000, 5000).slideUp(5000, function(){
                    });
                }
          });
}
```

calls a alert when succes fired, but the alert only appear for a very short time ( as page was reload). Where is myn fault using ajax call?

EDIT:

After trying, I change my html button code from:

```
<input class="btn btn-success submit-button" value="Submit"  onclick="myFunction()"/></input>
<input class="btn btn-success submit-button" value="Submit"  id=  "btnSubmit"/></input>
```

and js :

```
$(document).ready(function (){

     $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
     ....
```

and it works well. The use of `$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();` seems have not effect.

Comment: you can prevent the page reload with `preventDefault()`

Comment: tx, Please, read my edit part

Answer (score 3):

> You need `preventDefault()`. The `preventDefault()` method
>   cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action
>   that belongs to the event will not occur.

Try the following code:

```
function submitForm(e){

    e.preventDefault(); //This will stop from reloading
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var nomeCompleto = $("#nomeCompleto").val();
    var email    = $("#email").val();
    var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var parametros = {
              "nomeCompleto" : name,
              "email"        : email

      };

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "adminRegistro.php",
            data: parametros,
            async:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(parsedData){
                $("#ajax-alert").addClass("alert alert-danger").text(parsedData.msg);
                $("#ajax-alert").alert();
                $("#ajax-alert").fadeTo(5000, 5000).slideUp(5000, function(){
                });
            }
      });
 }
```

Comment: You should not use event as param since this is a keyword. Use function `submitForm(e){` instead and of course `e.preventDefault(); ` then.

Comment: This does not matter at all. I have tried it many times and it works without any problem

Comment: Tx, I tryed it. Please read my edit part. Anyway,  you helped me.